# Adding new keys to a dictioary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am coding a game inventory and i have a error message in my add to inventory function.
what i am trying to do here is create a new key if the item is not already in the dict and give it the value 1 and if the item is already in the inventory it increases its value by 1.
Happy for any Help i get:D

```
def add_to_inventory(inventory, added_items):
for row in inventory:
    if added_items[row] not in inventory:
        inventory[added_items[row]] = 1
    if added_items[row] in inventory:
        inventory[added_items[row]] +=1
```

This is the error i get:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: I think you want to run the `for` loop over `added_items` and not `inventory`...

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, and try to *read* and *understand* the error message. What do you think `TypeError` means? What do you think is the `tuple` it's complaining about, and what do you think is the `index` it's complaining about? What is the type of that index value? Does it make sense to you that the index `must be an integer or a slice`, and that a `str` will not work? Next, look at the data. The thing that is a `tuple` - *should* it be a `tuple`? How about its index?

Comment: See also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Error messages are not magic words that let experts know how to fix the problem. They are explanations of the problem - which anyone can learn to make sense of, but only by considering them in context and by tracing through the logic of the program. You have your entire program. We have six lines.

Comment: (That does **not** mean "show us your whole program". It means "trace backwards and try to figure out where the values are coming from, and especially check if something is not what you expect it to be".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the index of an item with a string.

```py
my_items = ('a', 'b', 'c')

my_items['a']
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Loop over `added_items` instead:

```py
for item in added_items:
    if item in inventory:
        inventory[item] += 1
    else:
        inventory[item] = 1
```